# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have created a Free style project which just check out the code from SVN. It was all working fine but suddenly I have start getting this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:621)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE

Can you please help me here how do I resolve this.

Comment: Have you updated any pipeline plugin recently? Check the workflow plugin.

Comment: Yes I was installing Cucumber reports plugin along with which few Pipeline plugins got updated. I have however tried the below remedies: 1. Tried restoring the plugins to the earlier version but no luck. 2. Deleted all the plugins and got them from a working a environment, no luck then. 3. Deleted all the plugins and installed them one by one from Jenkins UI itself, still of no help. I am using Jenkins 2.7.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after upgrading Jenkins to the latest version i.e. 2.89 along with latest plugins. The plugins were installed via Plugin Manager feature available in Jenkins.

Java 1.8
Jenkins 2.89

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrading the workflow-basic-steps plugin did the trick if you don't want tu upgrade your jenkins version.